# Any reason to backup gmail?

Tags: email, backup, gmail, web-services

My apologies if this question doesn't particularly fit here.

I figure some quick context to the question helps.
My Dad is a self employed insurance broker and has a home office. He's a proficient OSX user and uses Gmail as his primary email client with his business domain e-mail forwarded to it.

I know Gmail backup solutions are out there, for similar price we were even considering getting Exchange Online just as a backup solution. 
Though, I've been thinking, is there really a point to backing up Gmail?

It's already offsite and cloud based. He's not doing massive amounts of business, and the law doesn't impose any data retention requirements.

I'm thinking I should recommend he start using Google's softoken, to prevent losing control of his account, but is there a scenario I'm missing that would lead to wanting a Gmail backup service?

If anything was considering a local backup may be a smart idea, perhaps in the event of extended internet outage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If losing the email could adversely affect his business, then *yes*, back it up! In the event a GMail account is hacked, or GMail is down at a time when access is needed, a backup is a life-saver (well, business saver).

There is no need to buy any software to back up everything. One easy way to back up and to access the account is to install free [Thunderbird email client](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/), and set up an [IMAP connection to the account.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/imap-synchronization) GMail folders are copied locally to Thunderbird, but the original files are left on the GMail server. For redundant storage, create *local folders* in Thunderbird and copy (and sort) important email to it.

BTW, Thunderbird is available for OS X, Linux and Windows.

**N.B.** Just as in GMail viewed from a browser, Thunderbird allows you to manipulate (e.g. move, delete) GMail files on the server. Deleting an email in Thunderbird will also remove it from GMail.

Comment: Thanks so much for the recommendation. I understand he's using Carbonite as a file backup solution on his Mac as well, indeed that sounds excellent to have his full mailbox for offline access available. Are you aware perhaps if Thnderbird or another client could run as a background service on OSX and start at logon if rebooted to ensure it stays up to date?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Mac OS, but on Windows or Linux, I'd add it as a startup application. However, I would not recommend running it in the background -- use a password to protect the account, and then minimize it.